# MySQL "INSERT INTO SELECT NOT EXISTS" Efficiency

Tags: mysql

The following bit of code is causing me no end of headaches, it works; but it is taking upwards of 30min with only 16k rows; the final database will be looking to include 1-5M rows.

So I'm looking to make things more efficient

```
INSERT INTO r (aKey, bKey, c, d, e, fKey, g, h, i, j, k, l, mKey, nKey, o, pKey, qKey, r, sKey)
SELECT aKey, bKey, c, d, e, fKey, g, h, i, j, k, l, mKey, nKey, o, pKey, qKey, r, sKey
FROM t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT i,g
    FROM r
    WHERE t2.i = r.i AND t2.g = r.g
);
```

The field of i & g are the uniques (not specified in the DB currently - should they be? but a requirement)

Anything with Key on is a foreign key referencing another table

After the above statement I then loop through each none unique and update if it is different.

```
UPDATE r
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.i = r.i
SET r.d=t2.d;
```

I have looked into :

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

but I was never able to get it to work; as all the examples I found were not dealing with a insert select

Any suggestions to improve the SQL will be most helpful.

Comment: Can you post the result of "Explain Select ..."?

Comment: You will be better of with a left join/is null approach. Way faster than `where not exists`

Comment: @Jaydee For which SELECT statement needs the explanation?

Comment: Your WHERE NOT EXIST (Query) is probably making the query very long. If your table has 16000 rows, and each item only exists in 1000 rows, you end up with 16000 * 15000 iterations. You should look into a LEFT JOIN is null approach like @Nick mentiones

Comment: @Nick I'll try that when I get home, although I'm not sure if the WHERE is the slowest part of the query at present

As this query is generated through python code I was considering today breaking it into queries of no more than 1000 lines within a loop (16 small queries may be faster than 1 large query)

Comment: @StevenW when you use a select inside `where not exists` it becomes extremely slow. The left join will do exactly the same at a fraction of speed

Comment: please provide output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE r;`

Comment: Thanks all... I tried both; and reduced the number of updated columns but they were still taking 30m+ I suspect the sheer size and scope of the query was overloading the system I am running.

In the end I went back to basics and my unique columns in SQL were flagged correctly and I did an INSERT IGNORE on all the unique fields before looping through an update of all the individual queries.

Its not pretty but it works.... for now. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conclusion was: Due to the size of the request best to go back to basics and "set unique database fields to UNIQUE" and then do a INSERT IGNORE

Code below: (including python variable inserts)

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO """ + tblName + """ (""" + dupeString + """)
SELECT """ + dupeString + """
FROM t2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE """ + updateString + """;
```

dropped from 30-40m query to... less than 3 seconds.